# How to log requests and responses in Java Play Framework

Tags: java, logging, playframework, akka, slf4j

I'm a newbie to Java Play and I want to capture a request body and its corresponding response in the Java Play 2.5x framework. The goal is to log the requests and responses of APIs that fail N times per minute. I am using SLF4J for my logs. Also, when I am logging, I want to white out certain sensitive information such as credit card numbers or bank account numbers. How do I go about doing this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Filters is the best point for it:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters#A-simple-logging-filter